# Possible to hide an API key in .env file so its not tracked by git? React has "process.env.api_key" available, what can I do in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an API key for a movie database. It isn't particularly special to me but out of appreciation for the service, and to maintain good habits, I want to avoid committing this key to my git.

In React I can store it in a `.env` file as, for example, `API_KEY=someString` and then access it using `process.env.API_KEY`.

However, when I try to do this in Angular, I get:

`Property 'API_KEY' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['API_KEY'].ts(4111)`

So I follow its advice: `apiKey: string = process.env.['API_KEY'];` which gives me `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)` (understandable, its TS!)

I did some research about this and every thread out there says you "can't" secure an API key in client side code. I understand why people say that -- the api key is literally embedded into the code -- but it's not a concern here as the code will never run outside of a dev environment. I'm just learning.

So what I'm looking for is the equivalent of `process.env.API_KEY` from React. Thanks in advance for the hand holding.

edit: I'm aware I can run a proxy to a server side api call, i don't want to do that, it's overkill. Would consider it if I *couldn't* find an alternative to `process.env`

Comment: You don't mind it being exposed, so why not just include it as an export in a module? `export const API_KEY = "abc123";` Then import it in your app: `import {API_KEY} from "./secret-constants.js"` and add `./secret-contstants.ts` / `./secret-constants.js` to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: This worked for me! So simple I overlooked it. Had to set ```"allowJs": true``` in tsconfig but otherwise I'm all set

Comment: You can store it in a `.ts` file. I'm not sure whether that compiler option is necessary because I haven't used Angular, but I know in vanilla TS, you can use the `.js` extension in place of `.ts` and the compiler will resolve the `.ts` source file. (Compared to in React, where using an extensionless specifier is required.)